# If x is the position, how and why is one sure that a is displacement and b is acceleration in the given equation? x=a+bt²

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, displacement

I don't understand why a and b have to be displacement and acceleration respectively. Is that because of kinematics fist equation v-u+at?

Comment: Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem.   http://www.physicsclassroom.com/

Comment: You know that acceleration is $d^2x/dt^2$. What happens if you apply that yo your formula. (Also it is $2b$ that is the acceleration).

Answer (score 0):

"a" is certainly displacement or position because when you add two quantities of similar nature you get the result of same nature, simply differentiate the given equation twice wrt time and you'll get 2b. So b has dimensions of acceleration 
Ps: don't paste questions from your homework here

Answer (score 0):

In terms of dimensions (units) $x$ and $a$ have the same dimensions [L(ength)] and so if $x$ is a position $a$ will also be a position.

Assuming that $t$ is a time and has dimensions [T(ime)] then the dimensions of $b$ must be [L T$^{-2}$] to ensure that each term in your equations have the same dimensions.
So $b$ has the same dimensions as that for acceleration.